# Split string in Python using two conditions (one delimiter and one "contain")

Tags: python, string, split

Considering the following string:

```
my_text = """
    My favorites books of all time are:
    Harry potter by JK Rowling,
    Dune (first book) by Frank Herbert;
    and Le Petit Prince by Antoine de Saint Exupery (I read it many times).
"""
```

I want to extract the name books and authors, so expected output is:

```
output = [
    ['Harry Potter', 'JK Rowling'],
    ['Dune (first book)', 'Frank Herbert'],
    ['and Le Petit Prince', 'Antoine de Saint Exupery']
]
```

The basic 2-step approach would be:

- Use re.split to split on a list of non ascii characters ((),;\n etc) to extract sentences or at least pieces of sentences.
- Keep only strings containing 'by' and use split again on 'by' to separate title and author.

While this method would cover 90% of cases, **the main issue is the consideration of brackets ()**: I want to keep them in book titles (like Dune), but use them as delimiters after authors (like Saint Exupery).

I suspect a powerful regex would cover both, but not sure how exactly

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Basically the bullet list steps : first my_text.split('\n') to get sentences, then for each element containing 'by', sentence.split('by') and keep elements 0 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is "a powerful regex", but it does the job:

```
import re

text = """
My favorites books of all time are:
    Harry potter by JK Rowling,
    Dune (first book) by Frank Herbert;
    and Le Petit Prince by Antoine de Saint Exupery (I read it many times).
"""

pattern = r" *(.+) by ((?: ?\w+)+)"

matches = re.findall(pattern, text)

res = []
for match in matches:
    res.append((match[0], match[1]))

print(res) # [('Harry potter', 'JK Rowling'), ('Dune (first book)', 'Frank Herbert'), ('and Le Petit Prince', 'Antoine de Saint Exupery')]
```

Answer (score 0):

After splitting by lines with :

```
lines = my_text.splitlines()
```

You could then use a Regex such as `([A-Z0-9].*?) by ([a-zA-Z' -]+)` on each line.

This will match a capital letter (or a digit) followed by any character util   `by`  is encountered. The capital letter or digit is to avoid matching the "and " at the beginning of the last line, as I think most books start with either a number or a capital letter.

After the  `by` , the regex tries to match everything containing letters, apostrophes, spaces and dashes, as I guess it should match most English names. Feel free to add more characters, such as accents or different alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 're' module to make a strong regular expression to derive the desired answer. I wrote it with easy-to-understand code. If you go further, you can write your own simplified code.

```
import re

my_text = """
    My favorites books of all time are:
    Harry potter by JK Rowling,
    Dune (first book) by Frank Herbert;
    and Le Petit Prince by Antoine de Saint Exupery (I read it many times).
"""

output = []
for sentence in re.split(r'[;,\n]', my_text):
    match = re.search(r'(.*)\sby\s(.*)', sentence)
    if match:
        match_group_2 = re.sub(r'\s*\(.*\)', '', match.group(2))
        output.append([match.group(1).strip(), match_group_2.strip()])


print(output)
```

```
[
    ['Harry potter', 'JK Rowling'], 
    ['Dune (first book)', 'Frank Herbert'], 
    ['and Le Petit Prince', 'Antoine de Saint Exupery.']
]
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
import re

my_text = """
    My favorites books of all time are:
    Harry potter by JK Rowling,
    Dune (first book) by Frank Herbert;
    and Le Petit Prince by Antoine de Saint Exupery (I read it many times).
"""

lines = my_text.splitlines()

for line in lines:
    if " by " in line:
        line = re.sub("[!?:;,#*@]", "", line)
        title, author = line.split(" by ", 1)

        if "(" in author:
            author = author.split("(", 1)[0]

        print(f"{title}, {author}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it, and worked for me. I hope it is simple to understand.

```
import re

my_text = """
    My favorites books of all time are:
    Harry potter by JK Rowling, 
    Dune (first book) by Frank Herbert;
    and Le Petit Prince by Antoine de Saint Exupery (I read it many times).
"""  

# remove newlines
text = my_text.replace('\n', '')
# split on ":" and get the second element
text = re.split('[:]', text)[1]
# split on "," and ";"
text_list = re.split('[,;]', text)
# pattern for matching: "2 spaces", "and with 1 space", or end with "1 space+rounded brackets statements+period"
pattern = r"(\s\s+)|and\s|\s\((.*?)\)[.]$"
text_list = [re.sub(remove_space_pattern, "", text_element) for text_element in text_list]
# split on "space+by+space"
result = [re.split('\sby\s', element) for element in text_list]

print(result) # [['Harry potter', 'JK Rowling'], ['Dune (first book)', 'Frank Herbert'], ['Le Petit Prince', 'Antoine de Saint Exupery']]
```

Answer (score 0):

With short regex matching:

```
books = [[t, a.strip()] for t, a in re.findall(r'\s*(.+) by ([^(),;]+)', my_text, re.M)]
```

---

```
[['Harry potter', 'JK Rowling'], ['Dune (first book)', 'Frank Herbert'], ['and Le Petit Prince', 'Antoine de Saint Exupery']]
```